# why is this c program not giving me the output i want?

Tags: c

I am supposed to get 650. could someone please explain what I am doing wrong? I think the program is either not picking up the equation or printing it as the wrong data type.

```
int main(void) {
    int sales;
    int r = sales*9/100+200;
    printf("Enter sales in dollars (-1 to end): ");
    scanf("%d",&sales);
    printf(" Salary is:%d \n",r);
    return 0;
}
```

output:2416

Comment: The code, input and output should be posted as a properly formatted *text* in the question body itself.

Comment: sorry about that it is my first post, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: You add to `sales` before you ask the user to enter the value of `sales`.

Comment: Your IDE even warned you about that, see the notice on the right.

Comment: Post your code here as implicit text. It will be more helpful to the community to test and share the answer with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int r,sales;

    printf("Enter sales in dollars : ");
    scanf(" %d", &sales);

    r = sales * 9 / 100+200;

    printf("Salary is %d", r);

    return 0;
}
```

You must first get the value of sales before adding it to a formula.

Comment: that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, and can you please verify my answer since it helped you?Thanks!

Comment: ok, I just verified it, and sorry for the incorrect format. It is my first post and still learning how to use the website.

Comment: Thank you very much! Dont worry you will find your way around here quick, everybody is a beginner once :D

Comment: and dont worry about down votes. when you learn how to ask good question its they upvote it.  As a begineer just only concentrate on learn and do actual coding. good luck